# iOS: How to dynamically set height of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a view controller that contains a table view (see screenshot below). This table view always has exactly 3 rows, and these rows expand when clicked to show more information. How can I make it so that the table view's height always shows exactly these three rows, and no more? As you can see in the screenshot, empty rows with no content are being shown.

Note that the expanded rows may contain views other than UILabels.

Here's how it looks in IB:

[image]

Comment: How to do this depends somewhat on your design. How are you expanding the cells? Do you allow more than one cell to be expanded at once?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need something like this

```
//Return number of rows in section
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [self setTableHeight];
    return 3;
}

//Method which lets you calculate the height of tableView depending on your 3 cells
- (void)setTableHeight
{

    if(_isRowExpanded == NO)
    {
        tableHeightCalculated = rowHeight * 3; // rowHeight use default 44 or ur custom
    }
    else
    {
        //You need to put some logic here to Calculate or put approx height of  Expanded_Row_Height
        tableHeightCalculated = rowHeight * 2 + Expanded_Row_Height;

        if(tableHeightCalculated > maxHeightAllowed) //maxHeightAllowed is your current table height in snapshot
        {
            tableHeightCalculated = maxHeightAllowed;
        }
    }
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y,
                                 tableView.frame.size.width,  tableHeightCalculated);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is more space vertically than what is needed for displaying the actual cells, UITableView inserts fake empty cells. You can't really control this behavior, the most you can do is setting the height of your table view to something sufficiently smaller.

Comment: So how can I calculate the appropriate height?

Comment: But the height of one cell is dynamic, not some set value.

Comment: @JamesHarpe heard of variables? You can reload the table view and then it will ask its delegate again for table cell height data.

Comment: How can I determine what height to return for a row if that cell hasn't been loaded yet? If I could figure this out, I could use it to set the height of the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `frame` property of any control that you want to manipulate via programming. `frame` has further two properties of `size` and `origin`. Using the `size` property you can manipulate width and height and using the `origin` you can manipulate `x` and  `y` property of the control.
What you want can be done through:

`CGRect frame = control.frame; //control is your UIControl`

`frame.size.height = 10.0; //suppose 10 is the desired height.`

`control.frame = frame;`

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: How can I set this height value dynamically to the height of my three rows? How do I calculate this height?

Comment: if you want to set the height for the rows then the method you are looking for is:


`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
`

Using your `indexPath.row`, you can return any height that you want!

Comment: This doesn't help me set the height of the table. How can I calculate the height that the table view should have based on the height of my three rows?

Comment: why don't you set its height from the XIB file. Don't you think that would be easy for you to reduce the height from there. Default height of row is 44 so just put it 132 or something or is there something that either of us is missing in the details.

Comment: Yes, I could set an intial height of 132, but when a row is clicked, the cell will expand to show more views. I don't know the height of these views. So I need a way to get the new height of the cell after it expands and update the table height appropriately

Comment: Well, you can use a simple approach for that. You should put a flag property for the clicked row. and whenever you click on a cell, reload the cell using the `[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPath:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]]`. It will reload the row, so for each method in your data source and delegate you have to balance that check: return a bigger height, render a new view and onwards. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: When heightForRowAtIndexPath is called, the cell hasn't been created yet. So, how do I know how to set the height of the row? If I could figure this out, then I could use this to update the height of the whole table.

Comment: As I have told you, put a check on selected row so when all the methods are re-executed, separate results are shown on the basis of the flag condition.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I just need to know how to determine the height value to return in heightForRowAtIndexPath, given that I can't just use cell.frame.size.height, because the cell hasn't been created yet. I need some other way to determine what the height of the cell will be. Then, after the cell has been reloaded, I could just add the heights of the 3 cells and set the table view height to this value.

Answer (score 0):

try initializing the table´s footerview:

TableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];

Comment: This removes the empty cells, but does not change the height of the table. Effectively, it has the appearance of removing the extra lines in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Add this footerview method, This will work. This will remove the empty cells.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width, 0)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[tableView setTableHeaderView:v];
[tableView setTableFooterView:v];
return v;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this removes empty cells, but does not change the height of the table. It leaves a bunch of empty white space below my rows.

Answer (score 0):

This two lines work for me in the cases that I want the table looking exactly with the content size. It's an "illusion" but works like a charm.

```
 self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```